# USB Drivers not installing on deployed Dell machines Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, dell-optiplex

I have a number of machines to update to Windows 10 which currently run Windows 7.

I am specifically having issues with Dell Optiplex 760, 360 and 380 machines. I did have a similar issue with 780's but managed to sort that out by using windows built in drivers.

I found a video explaining how I have solved the issue on a single machine but I do not want to repeat this process 100+ times.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nSU3S0atjU

Any advice on installing USB drivers for any of the models above would be great from a System Center point of view. I am able to remove all the 360's and 380's from the environment but not able to do so with the 760's.

I have tried:

- No drivers from SCCM
- Just drivers for the model
- All drivers on SCCM
- Custom installing the chipset drivers (works but says drivers are
  older than windows current drivers which I guess is the reason it
  doesn't install them properly)

Comment: Windows 7 has the USB drivers built-in already.  So what drivers do you believe are not installed?  You shoudn't have to install USB drivers on either Windows 7 or Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, the entire USB controller fails to start and all USB devices fail on Windows 10 unless a driver is force installed (via remote desktop so you can actually use it)

Comment: So your saying that, if you install Windows 10, and allow Windows Update to install the generic device drivers.  Then the USB controller is not functional?

Comment: Its a 14 gig image pushed from SCCM with WSUS running on the SCCM server. We manage the drivers directly via SCCM which has worked perfectly with windows 7. There are no Windows 10 drivers supplied by Dell for the systems specified but the old drivers do work when force installed MANUALLY.

Comment: That does not really answer my question.  My thought process was, if you could get the generic Windows 10 drivers installed, you could then export those drivers and streamline the drivers into your deployed image.

Comment: I would go to the IT Professionals or Enterprise support community at support dot Microsoft.

Comment: Tried that, tried drivers direct from dell, from intel and windows own drivers. I think the issue could potentially be related to the machine the image was created on. The image was created on a much new machine and I am thinking that it may be carrying newer drivers over from that. Gives me a headache in UEFI support but I can live without UEFI for now.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I considered that but I usually don't get a lot of help from microsoft support forums. I thought I would try the stackexchange for a change. I considered posting the issue on serverfault but didn't consider drivers to be a server type issue.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I have been recreating the image from scratch (running into other issues along the way as you do) but simply installing on the machine from the disk works a charm. I am (eventually) going to capture it and test it and will post the result as the answer (if it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the WIM image from scratch on a Dell Optiplex 760 (worked perfectly from the disk), captured it and redeployed it focussing on 760 drivers only and it worked. Deployed to a 780, set just the 780's drivers, it installed.

The issue was caused by drivers being installed from one of the newer Dell Optiplex models during creation of the image, probably the 7010 and being built into the image so any applied drivers were older and therefore not applied correctly (or at all).

I now have a fight to have with the 760's display driver as its not been recognised but that's another story. I may be creating images on VM's in the future as drivers are unlikely to cause issues from a VM to physical hardware.

Comment: The 760 is a Sandbridge Q43 chipset with HD2000 onboard GPU,  Intel dropped support for HD2000 after 8.1.   :)  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005526.html#core

Comment: PS, If you can't find OEM drivers for W10 check the vendor.  Intel for example host drivers for IT deployment scenarios like yours. I had similar issues when reverting client machines to W7 on Skylake. The OEM was HP but the USB drivers could only be obtained from Intel.

Comment: Thanks for the info Robert, still gotta make it work! I have been able to literally strip it back and get it working with basic drivers. The image I had created caused me my issues which should never have happened.